# How does the window SUM function work with OVER internally?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to understand, how window function works internally.

```
ID,Amt
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
E,5
```

If I run this, will give sum of all amount in `total` column against every record.

```
Select ID, SUM (AMT) OVER () total from table
```

but when I run this, it will give me cumulative sum

```
Select ID, SUM (AMT) OVER (order by ID) total from table
```

Trying to understand what is happening when its `OVER()` and `OVER(order by ID)`

What I've understood is when no partition is defined in `OVER`, it considers everything as single partition. But not able to understand when we add `order by Id` within `over()`, how come it starts doing cumulative sum ?

Can anyone share what's happening behind the scenes for this ?

Comment: _internally_? Why bother - what's interesting for regular users is how to use it.

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056), it has very detailed explanation with examples. In general, *internally* means that you have to turn on some trace event and investigate the content of generated trace files. But your situation is fully documented: *If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.*

Comment: By definition, when you include the `ORDER BY` clause the engine will produce a cumulative aggregation; without it it produces the whole aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

That is an interesting case, based on the documentation here is the explanation and example.

> If **PARTITION BY** is not specified, the function treats all rows of the
> query result set as a single partition. Function will be applied on
> all rows in the partition if you don't specify **ORDER BY** clause.

So if you specifiey `ORDER BY` then

> If it is specified, and a ROWS/RANGE is not specified, then default
> **RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW** is used as default for
> window frame by the functions that can accept optional ROWS/RANGE
> specification (for example min or max).

So technically these two commands are the same:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) OVER (ORDER BY ID) total FROM table

SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) OVER (ORDER BY ID RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) total FROM table
```

More about you can read in the documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I doubt that documentation from Microsoft describes how Oracle is working internally.

Comment: I would remove the section related to `ROWS/RANGE` since it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Emim Mesic, then what would be the way of doing cumulative sum in every partition using this window function ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Oracle itself, but it's part of the SQL Standard and behaves the same way in many databases including Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, MariaDB, H2, etc.

By definition, when you include the `ORDER BY` clause the engine will produce "running values" (cumulative aggregation) inside each partition; without the `ORDER BY` clause it produces the same, single value that aggregates the whole partition.

Now, the partition itself is mainly defined by the `PARTITION BY` clause. In its absence, the whole result set is considered as a single partition.

Finally, as a more advanced topic, the partition can be further tweaked using a "frame" clause (`ROWS` and `RANGE`) and by a "frame exclusion" clause (`EXCLUDE`).